# NLTK parses but doesn't display a sentence diagram?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk

I want to parse *dextromethorphan abuse is underreported* using a feature-based context-free grammar in NLTK 3.0. The next to last line of the console output seems to indicate that the FCFG successfully parsed this sentence. However `tree.draw()` does nothing. On further inspection the generator `trees` contains no elements.

This console output doesn't look different (to me) from other outputs that also generate a tree. I have generated trees with other FCFGs with this NLTK configuration. What gives?

**My NLTK Code**

```
weasel_words = set(['moreover','likely'])
punkt = set(string.punctuation)

def deweasel(tokens):
return [token for token in tokens if token.lower() not in weasel_words
    and not token.lower().isdigit()]


cp = load_parser('./bip-grammar.fcfg',trace=2)
for tree in cp.parse(deweasel([token for token in word_tokenize(sentence) if token not in punkt])):
    tree.draw()
```

I've included `deweasel` for completeness. The error occurs whether `deweasel` is there or not.

**bip-grammar.fcfg**

```
 %start NP
 #Feature based context-free grammar
 #Base start is sentence

 S[NUM=?n,SEM=<?vp(?np)>] -> NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] VP[NUM=?n,SEM=?vp] 


 NP[NUM=?n,SEM=?np] -> N[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] 
 NP[NUM=?n, SEM=<\P.P(?np(?adj))>] -> ADJ[SEM=?adj] N[NUM=?n, SEM=?np]
 NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] -> ADJ[SEM=?np] 

 VP[NUM=?n,SEM=<?np(?vp)>] -> BV[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] PP[SEM=?np] PP
 VP[NUM=?n,SEM=?vp] -> LV[NUM=?n] NP[SEM=?vp]

 PP[SEM=?np] -> Prep NP[SEM=?np]

 N[NUM=sg, SEM=<\P.P(abuse)>] -> 'abuse'
 N[NUM=pl, SEM=<\P.P(reasons)>] -> 'reasons'
 BV[NUM=sg,SEM=<\y x.agree(x,y)>] -> 'agree'
 LV[NUM=sg] -> 'is'

 Prep -> 'with' | 'for'

 ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(DXM)>] -> 'dextromethorphan'
 ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] -> 'underreported'
```

**Console Output**

```
 |.dex.abu. is.und.|
 Leaf Init Rule:
 |[---]   .   .   .| [0:1] 'dextromethorphan'
 |.   [---]   .   .| [1:2] 'abuse'
 |.   .   [---]   .| [2:3] 'is'
 |.   .   .   [---]| [3:4] 'underreported'
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |[---]   .   .   .| [0:1] ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(DXM)>] -> 'dextromethorphan' *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |[--->   .   .   .| [0:1] NP[NUM=?n, SEM=<\P.P(?np(?adj))>] -> ADJ[SEM=?adj] * N[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] {?adj: <LambdaExpression \P.P(DXM)>}
 |[---]   .   .   .| [0:1] NP[NUM=?n, SEM=<\P.P(DXM)>] -> ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(DXM)>] *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |[--->   .   .   .| [0:1] S[NUM=?n, SEM=<?vp(?np)>] -> NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] * VP[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] {?n2: Variable('?n'), ?np: <LambdaExpression \P.P(DXM)>}
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   [---]   .   .| [1:2] N[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse)>] -> 'abuse' *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   [---]   .   .| [1:2] NP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse)>] -> N[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse)>] *
 Feature Single Edge Fundamental Rule:
 |[-------]   .   .| [0:2] NP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse(DXM))>] -> ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(DXM)>] N[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse)>] *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |[------->   .   .| [0:2] S[NUM=?n, SEM=<?vp(?np)>] -> NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] * VP[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] {?n: u'sg', ?np: <LambdaExpression \P.P(abuse(DXM))>} 
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   [--->   .   .| [1:2] S[NUM=?n, SEM=<?vp(?np)>] -> NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] * VP[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] {?n: u'sg', ?np: <LambdaExpression \P.P(abuse)>}
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   .   [---]   .| [2:3] LV[NUM='sg'] -> 'is' *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   .   [--->   .| [2:3] VP[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] -> LV[NUM=?n] * NP[SEM=?vp] {?n: u'sg'}
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   .   .   [---]| [3:4] ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] -> 'underreported' *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   .   .   [--->| [3:4] NP[NUM=?n, SEM=<\P.P(?np(?adj))>] -> ADJ[SEM=?adj] * N[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] {?adj: <LambdaExpression \P.P(underreported)>}
 |.   .   .   [---]| [3:4] NP[NUM=?n, SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] -> ADJ[SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] *
 Feature Bottom Up Predict Combine Rule:
 |.   .   .   [--->| [3:4] S[NUM=?n, SEM=<?vp(?np)>] -> NP[NUM=?n, SEM=?np] * VP[NUM=?n, SEM=?vp] {?n2: Variable('?n'), ?np: <LambdaExpression \P.P(underreported)>}
 Feature Single Edge Fundamental Rule:
 |.   .   [-------]| [2:4] VP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] -> LV[NUM='sg'] NP[SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] *
 Feature Single Edge Fundamental Rule:
 |[===============]| [0:4] S[NUM='sg', SEM=<underreported(abuse(DXM))>] -> NP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse(DXM))>] VP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] *
  |.   [-----------]| [1:4] S[NUM='sg', SEM=<underreported(abuse)>] -> NP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(abuse)>] VP[NUM='sg', SEM=<\P.P(underreported)>] *
```